# How to rename \cref{} for lstlisting

Tags: listings, cleveref

At the moment I'm working on my Diploma thesis and after a long time of searching and trying, I still can't find a solution for my problem.

Long story short: I want to refer to a **lstlisting**-enviroment via \cref{} and I want to change the displayed name. I already did this for some other enviroments:

```
\renewcommand\figureautorefname{Abbildung}
\renewcommand\tableautorefname{Tabelle}
\renewcommand\sectionautorefname{Kapitel}
\renewcommand\subsectionautorefname{Kapitel}
\renewcommand\equationautorefname{Gleichung}
```

I need to use \cref{} because I implemented a special format for the first use of \cref{}.

The result should be something like:

```
This is a test-Code: Program-Code 1
```

instead of

```
This is a test-Code: Listing 1
```

Could anybody help me?

Thanks a lot!

Chris

Edit: I found the part, that causes the failure of the solution under this post:
There is a part in the template of the university. In this part the german/english terms for supervisor/Examiner are defined for the titlepage. If I select the german version within the document-enviroment, Program-Code changes to Listing again. :-( I updated the Code.

---

Here is my example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                %% ermöglicht Sonderzeichen
\usepackage{lmodern}                    %% verbessert die Darstellung der Sonderzeichen
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}    %% deutsche oder englische Schreibweisen
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             %% deutsche Tastatur wg. Umlauten
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel} 
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}

\usepackage{subfig}                     %% Bilder => Unterbilder (a),(b),.. innerhalb einer Figure

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}                     %% farbige Schrift und Schrifthinterlegung

\usepackage{listings}               %% SOURCE CODE
\lstset{%                                                       settings for the listing package:
    numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny,%                           line numbers
    showstringspaces=false,%
    frame=b, framerule=1pt,%
    aboveskip=0.75\baselineskip, belowskip=0.75\baselineskip,%  space above and below listing
    breaklines, prebreak=\mbox{$\hookleftarrow$},%              break overlong lines and puts prebreak at the end
    stringstyle=\color{cyan}\ttfamily, % Farbe der String
    showspaces=false, % Leerzeichen anzeigen ?
    showtabs=false, % Tabs anzeigen ?
    xleftmargin=17pt,
    framexleftmargin=17pt,
    framexrightmargin=5pt,
    framexbottommargin=4pt,
    commentstyle=\color{8},
    showstringspaces=false, % Leerzeichen in Strings anzeigen ?
    morekeywords={__global__} % CUDA specific keywords
    }
\lstset{
    language=python,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{orange},
}
\lstloadlanguages{python}
\renewcommand*\lstlistingname{Programm-Code}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\hspace{15pt}#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white, singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt, font={bf,footnotesize}}

\renewcommand\figureautorefname{Abbildung}
\renewcommand\tableautorefname{Tabelle}
\renewcommand\sectionautorefname{Kapitel}
\renewcommand\subsectionautorefname{Kapitel}
\renewcommand\equationautorefname{Gleichung}

\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref}
\crefname{listing}{Program-code}{Program-codes}  
\Crefname{listing}{Program-code}{Program-codes}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\AtBeginDocument{% 
  \LetLtxMacro\oldref\cref% 
  \renewcommand{\cref}[1]{% 
  \ifcsname[#1]\endcsname\relax%
  {\oldref{#1}}%
  \else%
  {\textbf{\oldref{#1}}%
  }%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname[#1]\endcsname{1}%
  \fi%
  }% 
}

%-----

\declarebtxcommands{english}{%
\def\btxprue#1{\protect\foreignlanguage{english}{Examiner}}%
\def\btxsuper#1{\protect\foreignlanguage{english}{Supervisor}}%
}
\declarebtxcommands{ngerman}{%
\def\btxprue#1{\protect\foreignlanguage{ngerman}{Prüfer}}%
\def\btxsuper#1{\protect\foreignlanguage{ngerman}{Hochschulbetreuer}}%
}

\declarebtxcommands{ngerman}{%
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}
}
\declarebtxcommands{english}{%
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}
}
%-----

\begin{document}
%% SPRACHAUSWAHL VOR TEXTBEGINN
\selectlanguage{ngerman}   % <-------
%\selectlanguage{english}
\selectbiblanguage{ngerman}
%%\selectbiblanguage{english}


This is a test-Code: \cref{lst:example1}\\
second reference: \cref{lst:example1}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Test},label={lst:example1}]
test
\end{lstlisting}

Beispieltabelle: \cref{tab:test}\\
second reference: \cref{tab:test}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
 \captionabove{test-table}
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
 \hline
 hello & world \\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
\label{tab:test}
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: By the way, those redefinitions you show apply to the `\autoref` command (from `hyperref`), not to `\cref`.

Comment: You forgot to include the `babelbib` package.

Comment: Oh, of course, my thesis includes babelbib and babel, I'm sorry. But it doesn't change the problem. Included are:

    \usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}  
    \usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}

Comment: No, but it makes your example compilable, which I consider useful. (`\declarebtxcommands` is defined by `babelbib` it seems.)

Comment: Of course! It was my fault ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\crefname{listing}{Program-code}{Program-codes}  
\Crefname{listing}{Program-code}{Program-codes}
```

Add this after `\usepackage{cleveref}`. The first redefines the words (singular and plural) used for `\cref`, the second those for `\Cref`.

For your case there is some conflict with `babel` and the language selection commands. (There is some discussion around `babel` in section 10 of `cleveref`s manual.) Adding the `\crefname` *after* the `\selectlanguage` seems to fix the issue. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}    
\usepackage{babelbib}

\usepackage{listings}               
\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref}


\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}   % <-------
%\selectlanguage{english}
\crefname{listing}{Program-code}{Program-codes}  
\Crefname{listing}{Program-code}{Program-codes}

This is a test-Code: \cref{lst:example1}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Test},label={lst:example1}]
test
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Crazy sh**, it works in my minimal example, but it doesn't work in my Diploma thesis...
There is still "Listing"... But thanks anyway!

Comment: @Mr_Nofreeze Then you should try to create a new minimal example based on your thesis demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I updated my code with a new description of my problem

Comment: Perfect! That solves my problem! Many thanks!!!